# Get data from express with fetch

Tags: javascript, express, reactjs, fetch

I try to `alert` string which is variable in express.get and do to res. I wanna get in alert this "I am working fetch".

Here my **server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/publicServer'));

app.get('/fimlList', function(req, res) {
  console.log('i receive a GET request');

  var tryFetch = {myString: 'I am working fetch'};

  res.json(tryFetch)
})

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Server running on port 3000');
```

my **App.js**

```
import React from 'react';

var IchBinForm = require('./IchBinForm');
var SortFilms = require('./SortFilms');
var SearchFilm = require('./SearchFilm');
var FilmShort = require('./FilmShort.js');
var FilmLong = require('./FilmLong.js');

var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      list: {}
  },

  componentWillMount: function(){
    var fromServer = fetch('/fimlList')
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json()
    })
    .then(function(responseJson) {

      return responseJson.myString
    })

    alert(fromServer);

  },

changeShow: function(newShow, filmId) {...},    
  deleteFilm: function(id) {...},    
  seeForChangeInForm: function(change, id) {...},    
  addNewFilm: function() {...},   
  sortMe:function() {...},    
  searchMe: function(searchWord) {...},    
  howSearch:function(whichCheckBox, val) {...},

  render: function() {

    ....
        }
      }

    });

    return (...);
  }
});

module.exports = App;
```

and what I get:

[image: My alert now]

What do I do wrong ?

Comment: alert needs to be in the last `.then()`. The data arrives asynchronously...

Comment: I did it, but that return me undefined

Comment: instead of alerting `responseJson.myString` try logging just `responseJson` and see what you get out

Comment: You maybe misspelled `fimlList`? should it be `filmList`?

Comment: It is similar in server and app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You assign `fromServer` with a promise from fetch... 
You try to write code as it was synchronously while in fact it's asynchronously

Either move the code inside the last `then` function

```
.then(function(responseJson) {
    console.log(responseJson)
})
```

or use async/await to get a synchronously feeling while writing code

```
async function(){
    var fromServer = await fetch('/fimlList')
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json()
    })
    .then(function(responseJson) {
      return responseJson.myString
    })

    alert(fromServer);
}
```

if you go by the async/await approach i would suggest something more like this:

```
async function(){
    let response = await fetch('/fimlList')
    let responseJson = await response.json()
    let fromServer = responseJson.myString
    alert(fromServer)
}
```

Comment: I did it, but it return me undefined. What this mean ?

Comment: Yeah, you are funny. But I know what mean undefined, Instead, when i said "What this mean" I actually mean "Why it return undefined?". Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: maybe update the example in your question or provide an edit so we can see what you actually have. Might be a typo or something like that. It should work if you did what is suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You're not consuming your promise , try :

```
  componentWillMount: function(){
    fetch('/fimlList')
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json()
    })
    .then(function(responseJson) {
       alert(responseJson.myString);
    })
  },
```

Comment: I get:  localhost:3000 says: undefined

Comment: What is the defference ?

Comment: it shouldn't serialize response, but in your case you're parsing it in fetch method so that 's not the case...